# i want to insert same record for status=0 for the below code in mysql. but my logic is not working.can any one suggest me

Tags: mysql

I want to insert same record for status=0. But my logic is not working in MySQL.

Please add more text over here...

This question is about a stored procedure. And the user didn't provide any info what so ever.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_insert2`(
    IN P_page_Id int(11) ,
    IN P_LanguageCode char,
    IN P_page_status int(11),
    IN p_created_by int(11),
    IN p_created_date datetime,
    OUT P_return int)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_isRecordExisting int;
DECLARE v_flags int;

SELECT
    COUNT(*)
INTO
    v_isRecordExisting 
FROM 
    tbl_cms_pages_languages2
WHERE 
    page_status in(0,1) 
AND
    page_id = p_page_Id 
AND 
    languagecode = P_LanguageCode;

IF 
    v_isRecordExisting = 0        
THEN
    INSERT INTO tbl_cms_pages_languages2 (
        page_Id,
        LanguageCode,
        page_status,
        created_by,
        created_date
    )
    VALUES( 
        P_page_Id,
        P_LanguageCode,
        P_page_status,
        P_created_by,
        p_created_date
    );

    SET 
        p_return = 0; 
    ELSE
        SET 
            p_return = 2; 
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Please edit your question correctly and provide some more info.

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information, as it can be missed in the comments. You should also format your code properly and provide a clear concise description of the actual error you have - "not working" tells us nothing.

Comment: 1)IF page_status=x ,languagecode=y and page_status=0 insert my record 2)IF page_status=x ,languagecode=y and page_status=1 do not insert record  3)IF page_status=x ,languagecode=y and page_status=0 THEN AGAIN INSERT MY RECORD  can any one suggest me how to satisfy these three conditions for the above code

Comment: it is a stored procedure in mysql to insert data into a table